# Feed or alert of a specific Twitter keyword from specific Twitter account?

Tags: twitter

How do I receive an alert or create a feed for when a specific Twitter account tweets a specific keyword(s)?

For example, the author of a software application I use apparently does not have any type of feed dedicated to the updates for that software. I'd prefer not to follow his personal feed and monitor for that 1/100+ tweet mentioning the software update. I'd prefer to be notified in some fashion when they tweet a specific keyword. RSS is fine. Other tech/feed is fine.

Comment: You could use https://mentions.xyz/ to create an alert based on a Search query. I had a similar problem once and I wanted to get notified whenever someone tweeted about my blog. I built Mentions to solve this problem in a cheap way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a link to create RSS feeds on search.twitter.com, but it has disappeared. 
Fortunately the link itself is still working. You can insert any search operators you want (and use the from: tag to specify the user).

http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=from%3Aladygaga%20moment

...would search for tweets from ladygaga mentioning the word "moment".

Comment: It didn't disappear: https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced

Answer (score 1):

I have created a website just for this purpose called https://www.MyTweetAlerts.com.
You can set up email alerts based on your custom criteria. 
You should give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

If the user would use hashtagged keywords you could use my app, https://GroupTweet.com.  The resulting feed would just be the timeline of a new private or public Twitter account you created and then configured with GroupTweet. I can walk you through configuration if interested. Just contact us via our chat widget.